# How to modify this code to read very large files?

Tags: python, excel

I currently have this code to read excel files:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

This works fine for most of the stuff I deal with, however, I now have a giant excel file and this no longer works. I have found this code, which should solve my issue, but I am not sure how to store all of the lines so I can downsample the original excel file.

```
with open(filename) as f:
for line in f:
    <do something with line>
```

Is it possible in the above example to read all of the excel file and store it in

```
lines
```

To continue with my downsampling, so I don't need to modify more of my code (so take a line from the excel file, write it to lines, move onto the next, etc.)?

Comment: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Doesn't `readlines` read all the lines into `lines`? If you are storing line by line into `lines` again, aren't you doing the same thing?

Comment: The reason why the second code is better is because you don't have to load the whole file into memory at once. You load it one at a time. Therefore you don't care how big it is. You could add a `with open(filename) as f: lines = f.readlines()` but that would be doing the same thing as you are in the first place.

Comment: By downsample, do you mean you only want to store, say, every 5th line?

Comment: @MooingRawr Yes, I want to copy the first 4 lines exactly, and starting on the 5th lines, every 40th line.

Comment: @ciltut this is why you put more details in your question. Do the second `with open` and just have a counter in your for loop to read the first 4 lines and on the fifth one just have the `counter % 40 == 0` and then deal with that read line. Simple.